# Troubleshooting "class not found" error

Tags: php, whois

Anyone tell me why I'm getting the error "Class 'Whois' not found". It's something to do with the line `$whois = new Whois();` but I'm not sure what.

```
<form method="post" action="">
  <div style="margin:auto;width:300px;">
  <label for="domain name">Domain Check:</label><br />
  <input type="text" name="domain" /><br /><br />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
<br />
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['domain'])) { // check to see if form has been submitted
function getwhois($domain, $tld)
{
require_once("whois.class.php");

$whois = new Whois();

if( !$whois->ValidDomain($domain.'.'.$tld) ){
    return 'Sorry, the domain is not valid or not supported.';
    }

if( $whois->Lookup($domain.'.'.$tld) ){
    return $whois->GetData(1);
    }else{
    return 'Sorry, an error occurred.';
    }
}

$domain = trim($_REQUEST['domain']);

$dot = strpos($domain, '.');
$sld = substr($domain, 0, $dot);
$tld = substr($domain, $dot+1);

$whois = getwhois($sld, $tld);

echo "

";
echo $whois;
echo "
";
}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: var_dump( file_exists("whois.class.php") );

Comment: I've found the Whois class you're trying to use on the internet. :P And it should contain this: http://www.nott.org/uploads/whois.class.php.txt Does it actually contain that, or is it empty?...

Comment: This question should be removed / closed as it is non-beneficial to anyone, based on the comment in the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're loading this from the right directory

```
require_once("whois.class.php");
```

Comment: whois.class.php is in the same directory as this file

Comment: You're calling `function getwhois($domain, $tld)` before you require the class. as @Daniel says, try moving the require to the top

Comment: Is the error triggering when `if (isset($_REQUEST['domain']))` is true?

Comment: Paul -- Should be fine. PHP is usually fine with requiring files and defining classes inside functions.

Comment: ok this is stupid, turns out I had the wrong whois.class.php file.. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should move the `require_once` to the top of your file.